# Getting an array from a JSON Object

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Well I had a long post here with lots of data and sample code but I think I've realized the issue and am just looking for confirmation.

Specifically, when using json.getJSONArray(TAG) where json is a JSONObject, this will only work for the JSONObject nearest the array? IE, if there are

```
{"obj1": {"obj2": {"obj3": {"array":[]}}}}
```

then the call must be on object3.getJSONArray?   I had thought that I could pull any array out regardless of nesting but that appears not to be the case?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you should use

```
  obj1.getJSONObject("obj1").getJSONObject("obj2").getJSONObject("obj3").getJSONArray("array");
```

To reach that nested array.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right `getJSONArray` is searching array object on the level that you actually are.

To get Array you should go :
`JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject("{Oject 1: {Object 2: {Object 3: {[ARRAY]}}}}")
     JSONObject object1 = mainObject.getJSONObject("object 1");
    and so on till...
     JSONArray object1 = object2.getJSONArray("object 3");`

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the JSON format [here](http://www.json.org/).

Consider these two Java classes

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;
    private String value;
}

public class Bar {
    private int count;
}
```

and the objects

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.value = "some value";
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.count = 42;
foo.bar = bar;
```

Could you do

```
foo.count = 100;
```

? The answer is no. the field `count` belongs to the `Bar` object, not to the `Foo` object.

Same thing applies to JSON.

```
{
    "bar": {
        "count": 42
    },
    "value": "some value"
}
```

The `count` element is a JSON primitive that belongs to the JSON object named `bar`.

(The fact that it is a JSON array is irrelevant.)